# netbeans rcp adding to topcomponent at runtime

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am working on a netbeans RCP desktop application and have a need to add components dynamically. For example, I have a button which if I click on the menu should add components to the window at runtime. I have an actionlistener for the button and I added the following code in the action performed, but am not seeing the new component added. Any help is appreciated.

TopComponent editorTopComponent = WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("componentId");
            editorTopComponent.add(new JButton("TEST"));
            editorTopComponent.validate();
            editorTopComponent.repaint();
            editorTopComponent.updateUI();

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I somehow got it to work when I changed the layout of the TopComponent to FlowLayout, not sure if this is correct or not, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create now instance (more then one), then you can use :

```
MyTopComponent my = new MyTopComponent();
my.open();
my.requestActive();
```

if you want open TC in one instance (only), then you can use:

```
TopComponent editor= WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("componentId");
if(editor!=null){
  JPanel x =editor.getMyPanel();
  x.setVisible(false);
   //some changes
  x.setVisible(true);
  if(!editor.isOpened())editor.open();
}
```

Jirka